# Why does this Vue 3 form validation script fail?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am working on a *Users* CRUD application with Vue 3. I run into trouble while trying to validate the data in the "Add New User" form.

More precisely, I use the function below to make sure *no form field is empy*:

```
isNotEmpty() {
  return (
    this.formData.first_name &&
    this.formData.last_name &&
    this.formData.email
  );
}
```

For a reason I could not figure out, the `formErrors` array looks like this `["The email is invalid"]` instead of `["There are empty filelds","The email is invalid"]`;

```js
const usersApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      users: [{
          id: 1,
          first_name: "John",
          last_name: "Doe",
          email: "john.doe@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          first_name: "Jane",
          last_name: "Doe",
          email: "jane.doe@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      formData: {
        first_name: "",
        last_name: "",
        email: ""
      },
      formErrors: [],
      userAdded: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    isNotEmpty() {
      return (
        this.formData.first_name &&
        this.formData.last_name &&
        this.formData.email
      );
    },
    isEmail(email) {
      return String(email)
        .toLowerCase()
        .match(
          /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
        );
    },
    formValidation() {
      this.formErrors = [];

      if (!this.isNotEmpty) {
        this.formErrors.push("There are empty filelds");
      }

      if (!this.isEmail(this.formData.email)) {
        this.formErrors.push("The email is invalid");
      }

      console.log(this.formErrors);
    },
    resetAddFormData() {
      this.formData.first_name = "";
      this.formData.last_name = "";
      this.formData.email = "";
      this.userAdded = false;
    },
    addUser() {
      // Validate form data
      this.formValidation();

      // Make New User
      let newUser = {
        first_name: this.formData.first_name,
        last_name: this.formData.last_name,
        email: this.formData.email
      };

      // Add new user
      if (this.formErrors.length == 0) {
        this.users.push(newUser);
        this.userAdded = true;
        window.setTimeout(this.resetAddFormData, 1000);
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    users() {
      this.users();
    }
  }
};

Vue.createApp(usersApp).mount("#app");
```

```css
.logo {
  width: 30px;
}

.nav-item {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-item {
    width: auto;
  }
}

.users-table-item-active {
  transition: opacity 2s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.users-table-item {
  opacity: 1;
}

.alert {
  padding: 0.6rem 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>



<div id="app">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <!-- Brand -->
    <a class="navbar-brand p-0" href="#">
      <img src="https://www.pngrepo.com/png/303293/180/bootstrap-4-logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
    </a>

    <!-- Links -->
    <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
            Add user
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="card my-2">
      <h5 class="card-header px-2">Users</h5>
      <div class="card-body p-0">
        <table class="table table-striped m-0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Firstname</th>
              <th>Lastname</th>
              <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody name="users-table" is="transition-group">
            <tr v-for="user, key in users" :key="user.id">
              <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
              <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
              <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title h6" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Add New User</h3>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div v-if="this.formErrors.length > 0">
            <div v-for="error in formErrors" class="alert alert-danger">
              {{error}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div v-if="userAdded" class="alert alert-success">User added successfully!</div>
          <form @submit.prevent="addUser" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="First name" v-model="formData.first_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Last name" v-model="formData.last_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
              <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email address" v-model="formData.email">
            </div>
            <div class=" mt-2">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

###### What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like you forgot to actually call the isNotEmpty function. Right now the code is checking if the variable isNotEmpty is defined, and inverting the statement.

```
if (!this.isNotEmpty) {
    this.formErrors.push("There are empty filelds");
  }
```

Should be

```
if (!this.isNotEmpty()) {
    this.formErrors.push("There are empty filelds");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using computed boolean to check if your form is valid, you can use rules within each field like so :

## Define rules

Define rules in your `data` like :

```
rules: {
    notNull: v => {
      if(!v) return 'The field cannot be null'
      else return true
    },
}
```

## Add rules to your inputs

```
<v-text-field
   v-model='myModel'
   type='number'
   label='MyLbael'
   :rules='[rules.notNull]'
/>
```

## Check if your form is valid

Check if your form is valid with the condittion `this.$refs.myForm.validate()` (by specifying a ref to your form)